# Согласование существительного и причастия

Tags: согласование

В письме написано "Спасибо за теплое отношение к проблемам подростков, проживающим в приютах и находящимся в колонии...".
Разве не "проживающих и находящихся"?

Если "к подросткам", то "находящимся", а если "к проблемам подростков", то "находящихся". 
Или я не права?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы абсолютно правы. Определения "проживающих" и "находящихся" должны согласоваться с определяемым словом "подростков"